Aerial fibre installation plan: poles (point layer) need to be placed exactly 44m apart
The poles (point layer) need to be placed 44m part from each pole along the cable (line layer)
There are unfortunately over 3600 poles so it takes really long to sit and measure 44m and the place the pole(point layer)
I have drawn in all the poles is there any way to move them all to 44m apart.


Those who voted down this post: instead of just downvoting, it would be helpful to tell OP why it was downvoted and how they could improve the question. @DylanKew: your question is not clear enough. See [tour] about how to ask a good question.

What's fixed here? The line network, the number of poles, and the 44m separation? Is the line network connected? A solution might not even be possible.  What are these pole locations you've made - are they the right number of poles on each segment, just not exactly placed?

Even your manual approach is doomed for failure if you don't have a DEM and calculate 3D distance along the lines, and manual allocation ignores the fact that you have a computer sitting in front of you that is perfectly capable of computing 3D distance along lines. You're likely to have issues with the start and end points in the network not being a multiple of 44 meters apart, so you need to start over from the beginning and talk with your supervisor about the disconnect between reality and field conditions before you spend the entire budget doing this wrong.

It is probably easier to start over and create a new pole layer if you dont need to originate from your existing layer.
With Points along geometry you can create points every 44 m along your line layer.
If you need your original poles you can snap them to the points along geometry output.


This assumes that the topography is perfectly flat, so you may be setting the OP up for failure in the field, expensively..
